# Animate tile in Start Menu

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, tile

I would like to know if it is possible to animate the tile in the start menu of the WP7, much like the tile "foto's" is animated, or if this is restricted to Developers for Windows only ( I can image battery life etc. are taken in mind by the developers ). I have already looked at the ScheduledAgent, but the periodic agents typically run every 30 minutes, and only when the app is running in the background.

So, anyone knows if this is possible, or am I just wasting my time looking for a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the answer from @Ku6opr - you can create an animated tile without push notifications, or background agents. The application tile supports 'background' content. If you specify this, your tile will flip periodically while on the start screen to reveal the other side. Details of [how to use this feature are found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can change `Tile` only from: running application, `Background Agent` (30 min interval), Tile scheduler (1 hour minimum interval) or `Push Notification` (updates are not guaranteed)